i can not see the items of a cart in the checkout page of a simple ecommerce website using django
i can not see the items of a cart in the checkout page of a simple ecommerce website using django, the added products displays on the cart page but not in the checkout page,also when i want to place order in the checkout page nothing adds to order page of the django admin panel, the cart item of admin panel shows that the product is added but when i place the order no order comes in the order section of admin panel,here in below you can see the project codes:
models.py:
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    short_description = models.TextField()
    long_description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    production_date = models.DateField()
    product_id = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    #user


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_number, password=None):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a phone number")
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number)
        user.set_password(password)  # Set password if needed
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(phone_number, password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'

    objects = UserManager()
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_lable):
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number


class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.quantity} x {self.product.name}'


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    payment_choice = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    order_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Order {self.id} by {self.user.phone_number}"


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.product.name} in Order {self.order.id}"



views.py
import logging
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.db import transaction
import random
import django
from home.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from home.models import *

django.setup()


# Create your views here.
def product_list(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()  # Fetch all products
    return render(request, 'home/product_list.html', {'products': products})


# Dummy function to simulate sending messages
def send_otp(phone_number, otp):
    print(f"Sending OTP {otp} to {phone_number}")


def generate_otp():
    return str(random.randint(1000, 9999))


otp_store = {}  # In a real setting, save to a database or cache


def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(phone_number=phone_number)
            if created:
                # Generate OTP
                otp = generate_otp()
                otp_store[phone_number] = otp
                send_otp(phone_number, otp)
                return redirect('verify_otp', phone_number=phone_number)
            else:
                messages.error(request, "This phone number is already registered.")
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'home/signup.html', {'form': form})


def verify_otp_view(request, phone_number):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OTPVerificationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            otp = form.cleaned_data['otp']
            if otp_store.get(phone_number) == otp:
                # OTP is correct, user can be logged in or registered fully
                messages.success(request, "OTP verified successfully.")
                del otp_store[phone_number]  # Clear OTP
                return redirect('product_list')  # Redirect to login or homepage
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid OTP.")
    else:
        form = OTPVerificationForm()
    return render(request, 'home/verify_otp.html', {'form': form, 'phone_number': phone_number})


def view_cart(request):
    if isinstance(request.user, AnonymousUser):
        # Handle unauthenticated users
        cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
        cart_items = []
        total_price = 0
        for product_id, quantity in cart.items():
            try:
                product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
                item_total = product.price * quantity
                cart_items.append({
                    'id': product_id,  # This is crucial for the remove_from_cart URL
                    'product': product,
                    'quantity': quantity,
                    'total': item_total
                })
                total_price += item_total
            except Product.DoesNotExist:
                # Handle case where product no longer exists
                pass
    else:
        # Handle authenticated users
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        total_price = sum(item.product.price * item.quantity for item in cart_items)

    return render(request, 'home/cart.html', {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total_price': total_price})


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@login_required
def checkout(request):
    user = request.user
    logger.info(f"Checkout initiated for user: {user.username}")

    # Fetch cart items
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=user)
    logger.info(f"Number of cart items retrieved: {cart_items.count()}")

    # Log each cart item
    for item in cart_items:
        logger.info(f"Cart item: {item.product.name}, Quantity: {item.quantity}, Price: {item.product.price}")

    # Calculate total price
    total_price = sum(item.product.price * item.quantity for item in cart_items)
    logger.info(f"Total price calculated: {total_price}")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        logger.info("POST request received for checkout")
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        payment_choice = request.POST.get('payment_choice')

        logger.info(f"Address: {address}, Payment Choice: {payment_choice}")

        if not address or not payment_choice:
            logger.warning("Missing address or payment choice")
            messages.error(request, "Please provide both address and payment choice.")
            return render(request, 'home/checkout.html', {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total_price': total_price})

        if cart_items.exists():
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    logger.info("Creating order")
                    order = Order.objects.create(
                        user=user,
                        address=address,
                        payment_choice=payment_choice,
                        order_price=total_price
                    )
                    logger.info(f"Order created with ID: {order.id}")

                    for cart_item in cart_items:
                        logger.info(f"Creating OrderItem for product: {cart_item.product.name}")
                        OrderItem.objects.create(
                            order=order,
                            product=cart_item.product,
                            quantity=cart_item.quantity,
                            price=cart_item.product.price
                        )

                    logger.info("Deleting cart items")
                    cart_items.delete()

                    messages.success(request, "Order placed successfully!")
                    logger.info(f"Order {order.id} placed successfully")
                    return redirect('order_detail', order_id=order.id)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error creating order: {str(e)}", exc_info=True)
                messages.error(request, f"An error occurred while processing your order: {str(e)}")
                return redirect('view_cart')
        else:
            logger.warning("Attempted to checkout with empty cart")
            messages.error(request, "Your cart is empty.")
            return redirect('view_cart')

    logger.info("Rendering checkout template")
    return render(request, 'home/checkout.html', {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total_price': total_price})


def add_to_cart(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    logger.info(f"Adding product to cart: {product.name}")

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(product=product, user=request.user)
        cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
        logger.info(f"Added to CartItem for user {request.user.phone_number}: {cart_item}")
    else:
        cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
        cart[str(product_id)] = cart.get(str(product_id), 0) + 1
        request.session['cart'] = cart
        logger.info(f"Added to session cart for anonymous user. Cart contents: {cart}")

    messages.success(request, f"Added {product.name} to your cart.")
    return redirect('view_cart')


def remove_from_cart(request, item_id):
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(id=item_id)
    cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('view_cart')


def checkout_redirect(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('checkout')  # Replace with the actual checkout URL name
    else:
        return redirect('signup')  # Replace with the actual login URL name


@login_required
def order_detail(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id, user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'home/order_detail.html', {'order': order})


checkout.html
<html lang="en">
<body>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2>Checkout</h2>
    <label for="address">Shipping Address:</label><br>
    <textarea name="address" required></textarea><br>

    <label for="receiver">receiver:</label><br>
    <textarea name="receiver" required></textarea><br>


    <label for="payment_choice">Payment Method:</label><br>
    <select name="payment_choice" required>
        <option value="online">Online</option>
        <option value="pay_on_delivery">Pay on Delivery</option>
    </select><br>

    <button type="submit">Place Order</button>
</form>

<h3>Your Cart Items:</h3>
<ul>
    {% for item in cart_items %}
    <li>{{ item.product.name }} - {{ item.quantity }} @ {{ item.product.price }} each</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% for item in cart_items %}
    <div class="product-item">
        <p>{{ item.product.name }} ({{ item.quantity }})</p>
        <p>Price: ${{ item.product.price }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart'  item.id %}">Remove</a>
    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <p>Your cart is empty.</p>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>

ur
# urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
from home.views import *

# urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from home.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('signup/', signup_view, name='signup'),
    path('verify-otp/<str:phone_number>/', verify_otp_view, name='verify_otp'),
    path('cart/', view_cart, name='view_cart'),
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    path('remove/<int:item_id>/', remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
    path('checkout/', checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/', order_detail, name='order_detail'),
    path('checkout/redirect/', checkout_redirect, name='checkout_redirect'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='home/checkout.html'), name='checkout'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

ls.py if necessary
i have traced the the orderitem loop codes from the checkout page to view and model but it looks fine to me,i used the suggestions of AI but nothing happened,also cleared the browser cache and rerun the local server but all useless

the problem was in the url pattern instead of redirecting to checkout url it was set to redirrect in login url.
